# Fix TypeScript Autocomplete for RxJS Operators in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm, rxjs

I'm using WebStorm for an Angular 2 project.

I code in TypeScript and in one of my components I use `Observable` :

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({...})
export class SearchComponent {

  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let inputElement = this.input.nativeElement;
    let keyups = Observable.fromEvent(inputElement, 'keyup');  // <-- WebStorm error
    keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

This code does work (something is logged to the console every time I type something in the input field), but WebStorm complains about the `fromEvent` method ("Unresolved function or method").

Also, if I trigger autocomplete on the `Observable` class, most of the operators listed in the RxJS documentation are missing. For instance, typing `Observable.fr` should produce a list of `from`, `fromCallback`, `fromEvent`, `fromPromise`... but WebStorm only suggests one method (`withLatestFrom`).

How can I get proper autocomplete/TypeScript support for observables in WebStorm?

I have tried different ways to import `Observable`, I have tried the suggestions in [this article](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/04/19/typescript-rxjs-intellisense-node) (i.e. adding `"files": ["node_modules/rxjs/Rx.KitchenSink.d.ts"]` to `tsconfig.json`), but nothing worked.

Comment: Which version of WebStorm are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using PhpStorm 2016.1.2, but both PhpStorm and WebStorm are based on IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I was just wondering, if you're using the latest version, but since that's the case, I don't really know a possible solution.

Comment: Try 2016.2 EAP build -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-844/ . P.S. latest stable is 2016.1.3

Comment: LazyOne: Correct, thanks. Jetbrains suggested the same thing and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, even with WebStorm 2016.2 (final). The solution that worked for me was in a comment to another answer, so to make it more visible, here it is as a proper answer:

#### Delete the `.idea` folder.

I did this, and then restarted WebStorm. Then all the rxjs definitions worked.

Comment: There is a "invalidate and reset" feature in the Files menu. Use that instead of deleting `.idea` folder.

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` folder worked in PHPStorm 2016.3.2 as well.

Comment: **Definitely don't** do this if you have any settings you care about.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using WebStorm 2016 and this helped me with my angular 2 + ionic 2 project:

```
WebStorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries 
-> [Ensure 'ECMAScript 6' and 'your-progect/node_modules' are checked]
.then Apply -> Save -> Restart WebStorm
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a problem with PhpStorm.

I reached out to Jetbrains support, and they suggested upgrading to version 2016.2 EAP (Early Access Program), which does fix the problem.

Comment: 2016.2 is NOT "current latest version". Current latest version is 2016.1.3. The 2016.2 is in EAP state at the moment (Early Access Program -- sort of beta version, to make it easier to understand)

Comment: I have version #WS-162.917.18 (2016.2 EAP), still having this issue.

Comment: @gattsbr I still had the issue until I deleted `.idea/`

Answer (score 1):

Try these settings to see if webstorm picks it up

tsconfig.json ( in the root of your angular2 project )

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

In your package.json ( Install typings if you havent already )

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
```

create the file typings.json in the root of your project and/or make sure you have these added in your typings added in the file

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

After all this run (to install the new dev modules

> npm install

then install the typings by running this command

> typings install

Switch to Webstorm/Phpstorm and allow the IDE to finish indexing. Then check to see if Webstorms autocomplete has more than one method related to Observables.

Try importing Observables in your project files like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Might not be the answer your looking for but worth trying since people are running out of ideas.

EDIT: fixed file name not **typing.json** should be **typings.json**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Nige. Looks like the various settings you're recommending are analog to those found in the Quickstart, and they're the ones I'm already using in my project.

Comment: Alright. Was just wanting to double check you never know. Seems really strange. I am using the exact same version and my Observable auto complete has multiple methods attached to it :/ tried just deleting your .idea in the root of your application and reopening the project?

Comment: I upgraded to version 2016.2 EAP and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with a similar issue on WebStorm 2016.3 and was lucky to resolve it by configuring IDE to use `rxjs` as a javascript library:

1. Go to "Preferences" and open "Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries".
2. Click on "Add..." and set following fields:

   - Name: rxjs
   - Framework type: node_modules
   - Visibility: project
   - Click on "+" button and attach a directory of `rxjs` which is under project's `node_modules` directory.
3. Click on "OK" and make sure that the library is applied on a project level.